# Luxon migration: moment.utc()

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

I'm working on migrating our codebase to Luxon from moment, and I've run into an issue that I cannot find a solution for.

```html
<script type="module">

import {default as moment} from 'https://unpkg.com/moment@2.29.4/dist/moment.js';
import * as luxon from 'https://unpkg.com/luxon@3.0.1/build/es6/luxon.js';

const momentObject = moment.utc(
  input, // Moment object or valid date string
  this.acceptedFormats(), // Array of acceptable formats, which returns true or false when isValid() is called
  true // Use strict parsing?
);

</script>
```

How can I create a similar object with Luxon, which will return false when accessing momentObject.isValid?

Comment: Hi Jeramiah Coffey: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to check out the article on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The code you've shown is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it's going to be tough for someone to provide help answering it. I've edited your question to include imports for moment and luxon, but the other referenced variables in your question are still not defined (`input` and `this.acceptedFormats`).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that your suggestion on how you're about to use moment.utc(..) function above (especially 2nd parameter usage) is not the way to approach to the solution you need as mentioned. However, I do have a minimal example for you - see https://codepen.io/brifiction/pen/WNzaebE/4469095d511b1ed0def2720bc4de5f90?editors=1010. If you like it, I can post this snippet as an answer for you ;)